# Multi ImageLoaders with Picasso library in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, picasso

I'm using [**Picasso Library**](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and i have (*for example*) **five** `ImageView` and i need to show them with `Picasso`and i know we can do like this:

```
ImageView footer1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail1);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://url.com/1.jpg").into(footer);

        ImageView footer2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail2);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://url.com/2.jpg").into(footer);

        ImageView footer3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail3);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://url.com/3.jpg").into(footer);

        ImageView footer4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail4);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://url.com/4.jpg").into(footer);

        ImageView footer5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail5);
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("http://url.com/5.jpg").into(footer);
```

But, can we use `AsyncTask` for load these multiloading?

Or what is the best way for do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Picasso` in the above case is a singleton instance, meaning you aren't creating a new `Picasso` object each time you load an image. Also the Images are loaded intelligently on a background queue with a designated task dispatcher so doing what you are doing above is perfectly fine. Do it in a loop if you need to cut the code.

You can of course use `AsyncTask`, but it will not make it any faster. In contrary it will bring more code complexity and overhead.

Picasso will also automatically manage the number of images it tries to download at once depending on device connection type (3G, Wifi etc).